# Grafana dashboard using MySQL: how should I deal with timestamp of "%Y%m%d%H%i%s" to use as time column of panel?

Tags: mysql, grafana

I want to visualize my MySQL DB table to an hourly basis graph using Grafana dashboard. The table that I'm working with has the attributes below, with unused ones including PK not mentioned:

```
SERVER_NAME varchar(250)
STAT_TYPE int(11) 
STAT_DTM varchar(14) 
CPU_MAX_USAGE int(11) 
MEMORY_MAX_USAGE int(11)
```

What matters is `STAT_DTM`. Its format is `"%Y%m%d%H%i%s"`, e.g. `"20210621090000"`; for 09:00:00 of June 21st 2021. I want this to be the X axis of the graph. Grafana guide says:

> return column named time or time_sec (in UTC), as a unix time stamp or
> any sql native date data type. You can use the macros below.

So I put `unix_timestamp(date_format(str_to_date(substr(stat_dtm, 1, 10),'%Y%m%d%H'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'))` but an error saying `db query error: query failed - please inspect Grafana server log for details` popped up.

```
select
    unix_timestamp(date_format(str_to_date(substr(stat_dtm, 1, 10),'%Y%m%d%H'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')) as 'time',
    CPU_MAX_USAGE,
    MEMORY_MAX_USAGE
from lcop.tb_stat_os_day
where stat_type = 60 and server_name = 'LDFSWAS1'
```

[The Panel I'm currently working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1m4a.png)

[The result of the query above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFLT0.png)

How can I set the timestamp correctly and show the graph? The table schema cannot be modified unfortunately and I can give any additional info if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _" .. a unix time stamp or any sql native date data type"_ it seems to me like it don't have to be unix timestamp?

Comment: @FaNo_FN yup so i tried ```date_format(str_to_date(stat_dtm, '%Y%m%d%H%i%s'), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')``` too but i think this one doesn't work as well tho

Comment: Actually, with that function, you're converting '20210621090000' to '2021-06-21 09:00:00' with `STR_TO_DATE` then you convert it back to '20210621090000' using `DATE_FORMAT`.. [see here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2833d5d79a78850d57c4defd70813147)

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify your type conversion there:

```
SELECT '20210621090000' as `src`,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('20210621090000', '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')) as `dts`
```

The `STR_TO_DATE()` function can be given the full format, which can then be given to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. There is no need to make things more difficult with `SUBSTR()` or `DATE_FORMAT()`

Comment: Thanks buddy I had gone way too far. That works just as I want and it's much shorter.